# Styled components + typescript: "as" is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a monorepo that contains a design-system made with styled components. In this design system I have a Heading component that takes a 'level' prop to adjust the CSS of the heading.

**Heading**

```
export interface HeadingProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
    level: 'colossus' | 'uber' | 'hero' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5'
}

export const Heading: React.FC<HeadingProps> = ({ level = '1', children, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <HeadingStyled level={level} {...rest}>
            {children}
        </HeadingStyled>
    )
}
```

**Usage**

To use this Heading component I simply pass a `level` to it for the styling and the `as` prop to adjust what HTML is rendered.

```
<Heading as="h2" level="2">
    Header 2
</Heading>
```

**Problem**

When I use this component I get a typescript error on the `as` prop

```
Type '{ children: string; as: string; level: "2"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeadingProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Property 'as' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeadingProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

I have tried:

```
export interface HeadingProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
    level: 'colossus' | 'uber' | 'hero' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5'
    as?: React.Element | JSX.Element | JSX.IntrinsicElements
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `as?: React.Element | JSX.Element | JSX.IntrinsicElements | string`

Comment: No matter what I put the error `Property 'as' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HeadingProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.` remains the same

Comment: restart typescript/bundler

Comment: It's not [recommended](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) to use React.FC and there's no current documentation to be found for it on the React website. If it's an option, maybe try implementing regular function or class components in Typescript instead.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do? Do you want to pass all styled-component props through transparently? Or only the `as` prop?

Comment: @Jason does my answer help?

Comment: Seeing as my answer solved your problem it would be cool to accept the answer and award me the bounty @Jason McFarlane :)

Comment: Sorry mate I was away, the answer was helpful but I ended up changing some of my stuff around anyways

Comment: No worries mate. Any chance you can award me the bounty you assigned to the question?

Comment: its not giving me an option or I would

Comment: Looks like the bounty expired yesterday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're close! `JSX.IntrinsicElements` is an interface whose *keys* are the labels of the HTML tags. It itself is not a union of all HTML tags.

That means that all you need to do is

```
interface HeadingProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
    // ...
    as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements // Note the keyof!
}
```

Now `as`'s signature is shown by TS as:

```
(JSX attribute) HeadingProps.as?: "symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | "canvas" | ... 156 more ... | undefined
```

Which means your code will now work exactly as expected

```
<Heading as="h2" level="2"> // No TS errors! ✅
    Header 2
</Heading>
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BnGATwBskATObXA2xlgWjV0gA7JIJjUypUv0G04ACVTNgggOYBlek1YBeGppYA6JQDcABqclIAHpXjKYSKJnRJ5i5SoAKOMNTjWHQWY-OQAVAFkAGQBBGBgoYAAjAFcHagAeMKiFFCVVAFEmEBEYAD44AG9SODgmYyQGAC4CfgYIampk8TgAHwJkxMd8XoIAC0cIYb78AEYpggAmefwAZmWAFmWAVjIalGoAfmaAayQ6CEw4ACk1AA0DAElRBJlgNEKkYtFqUgBfSUsNmg8GkshyeRUzWQ6BgBgAYgBhTLuVTeCC%20cq6AAUFVqSHqDDgulm%20AANHA0KNgAxmERBOSDIyiLJfgBKInlKo1IgwZJQQRwLHVGpwZG5DwabisfbafDDCqMgzMmC-UrCkWVSnU2kif4a9IAenBEv0zDVNVZfwBoPg%20SsKHATAAqtQUCpXNj2dpykKamKIXAZQAiUYLIN4gnaINh80i8GOOALYWG42qNWsoA)

Comment: @Jason McFarlane This solution is incomplete and does not behave in the way that `as` prop does, because `as` changes available props of the generic styled component. It's far more complicated than the proposed interface. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/styled-components/index.d.ts

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak sure, but that wasn't in the original question

Answer (score 0):

in completion to [@Aron's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65827138/13398368) answer , this code working for me (`styled-component + styled-system`)

```
{ as?: ComponentType<any> | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | string | undefined }
```